# Bluetoth headset microphone not working - HSP/HFP unavailable

Tags: audio, bluetooth, microphone

Im usuig Ubuntu 20.04 and try to use my headset (Xiaomi Mi True Wireless) for video conferencing, so sound input and output are required. When try to select the HSP/HFP Profile in pavucontrol I get only the choice between:

- High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)
- Headset Head Hnit (HSP/HFP)(unavailable)
- High Fidelity Capture (A2DP source)(unplugged)(unavailable)
- off

When I select HSP/HFP just nothing happens, and after restarting the program, A2DP sink is selected again. So why is the HSP/HFP profile unavailable and how to make it available/ how to use it?

Comment: Are you using PulseAudio or PipeWire?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved for me by:

- Configuring Pipewire as the default server (https://askubuntu.com/a/1339908/191003)
- Restarting Bluetooth service: `sudo service restart bluetooth`

Not sure if by just restarting the Bluetooth service was enough though.